# Get Values from Enum dynamically at Runtime

Tags: java, enums

My enum types-

```
public enum Foo {A, B, C}
```

And

```
public enum Bar {A("aaa"), B("bbb"), C("ccc")}
```

All I have at runtime is the enum class name i.e. "Foo"

I do this -

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(getClassName()) // local function
```

Using `Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants())` gets me -

Foo -

```
[A, B, C]
```

Bar -

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc]
```

I also want `[A, B, C]` when evaluating `Bar`.

`.values()` is what I want but how do I get to it dynamically without any explicit casting?

Many thanks for any replies.

#### Have found the solution -

```
List<? extends Enum<?>> enums = (List<? extends Enum<?>>) Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants());
for (Enum<?> e: enums) {
    System.err.println("e.name: " + e.name());
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at my Answer?

Comment: You should post your own solution as an answer, not as a part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your `Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants())` is actually working correctly. What you are seeing when you print the array out is a list of the `toString()` results of `Bar` which become `[aaa, bbb, ccc]`.

Try something like:

```
for (Bar b : Bar.class.getEnumConstants()) {
  System.out.println(b.name() + "(\"" + b.toString() + "\")");
}
```

You should see what I mean.

If you have an `enum` that defines its own `toString()` you could try wrapping it:

```
static class EnumNamer<T extends Enum<T>> {
  final T he;

  public EnumNamer(T he) {
    this.he = he;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return he.name();
  }
}

public void test() {
  System.out.println("Hello");
  for (Bar b : Bar.class.getEnumConstants()) {
    System.out.println(b.name() + "(\"" + b.toString() + "\")");
    EnumNamer<Bar> en = new EnumNamer<>(b);
    System.out.println(en + "(\"" + en.toString() + "\")");
  }
}
```

Now you've clarified a few points - this works for me:

```
// This cast should be OK so long as we KNOW its an enum.
Class<Enum> c = (Class<Enum>)Class.forName(Bar.class.getName());
for (Enum e : c.getEnumConstants()) {
  EnumNamer en = new EnumNamer(e);
  System.out.println(en + "(\"" + en.toString() + "\")");
}
```

Comment: Ah, yes it does override toString.  The question is, how do I get round this without altering the enum?

Comment: Get around what? Perhaps don't call `toString()`. Perhaps call `.name()` instead.

Comment: '.name()' is not available off of 'getEnumConstants()' and as I stated, I cannot do any explicit casting...

Comment: `.name()` **is** available from `getEnumConstants`. See my sample code `System.out.println(b.name() ...`.

Answer (score 0):

For `Bar` You can use the following code while retrieving the constants:

```
List<Bar> list = Arrays.asList(c.getEnumConstants());
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Bar b : list)
{
   list1.add(b.name());
}
System.out.println(list1);
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon: In that case OP can use `.name()` method of `Enum` as I have done in my updated code..